# Objects unable to capture ID from XML in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been trying to make a simple randomizer app that takes an upper and lower bound from user input and displays a random number in between. However, a bunch of my objects don't capture the ID from the XML at all.

Here's the beginning of my OnCreate method for this (second) activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mode2);

    Button altRollButton = findViewById(R.id.altRollButton);
    TextView altResultHeader = findViewById(R.id.altResultHeader);
    TextView altResult = findViewById(R.id.altRollResult);
    EditText fromValue = findViewById(R.id.fromValue);
    EditText toValue = findViewById(R.id.toValue);
    FloatingActionButton switchModeButton = findViewById(R.id.switchModeButton);
```

And here are the XML ID entries, respectively:

```
    android:id="@+id/altRollButton"
    android:id="@+id/altResultHeader"
    android:id="@+id/altRollResult"
    android:id="@+id/fromValue"
    android:id="@+id/toValue"
    android:id="@+id/switchModeButton"
```

If I debug the code and put a breakpoint after all instantiations, here's the log - [image: debug log]

Seems like half of my objects properly capture the ID, and the other half don't, and I've been trying to solve this for the past 2 days with no success. Any ideas are very much welcome!

Comment: Blind guess - aren't you calling `findViewById` **before** setting view content?

Comment: I'm calling it after that. Here's how the entire file looks like - https://pastebin.com/tK4fug72

Comment: Do not post code externally. If that matters, edit your question and add additional info (i. E. `onCreate()`, stacktrace etc).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've reworked my question so it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the source of the issue. Turns out in the AndroidManifest.xml file I had another default activity with no contents in it and when I commented that out the IDs are now properly captured and everything works as expected.

Comment: hold on. then it means you were debugging wrong class  and the code in question is not related.

Comment: Indeed, it would seem that the active class was the blank, default activity. I have no idea how that happened, but glad I was able to spot it nonetheless. Shall I delete this question entirely now, as it serves no real purpose?

Comment: No, that's fine. I just left this as a comment to point out that you were looking at the wrong place. There's nothing wrong with that.